# Docker Revert Changes

Tags: docker

I pushed an image to docker called abc:latest. Unfortunately when I did that, all my code fails to run which was working before in the old docker image. This is the history. I want to see how to revert to 3x6427292cl5 and if its possible given I updated latest.

```
IMAGE              CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
w667h0256813        43 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh" "-c…   0B                                 
3x6427292cl5        10 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG VDP_BUILD_GEN            0B                  
c4dddee52n01        10 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B                  
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL name=Photon OS x86_…   0B                  
<missing>           7 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:a702523c66281e085…   25.6MB
```

Comment: That history doesn't show anything added / removed. It's just the entrypoint. Can you list the images with `docker images -a`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid there's no way to do that.

For next times, a good practice is using a versioning: `abc:X.Y.Z` (I recommend semantic versioning semver.org), and use `latest` as just a link to higher version.

Furthermore, I highly recommend protect your repo to avoid uploading of several images with different code and same tag.